# Get data from an API to my server every minute

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-mvc-4

Here's an API server which can give me real time news: every minute there will be something new to retrieve. There's also my web page, with a Javascript that will ask the API to get some news once every minute.

And this is not fine... unless my web page is made for a single user and will be open only on one machine at a time (which is not the case of the internet). the API, infact, restricts the number of call I can do per minute: let's suppose the API will ban me if I do more than 1 call per minute. If 100 users will load my web page, the API will receive 100 calls per minute (!!!).

Since the flow is my web page >> calls >> the API I think there is no solution without inserting another node which lazy loads from the api server.

my web page >> calls >> my server >> calls every minute >> the API

Since the instances of my web page may be many while my server is just one I think this is the solution.

However, I have no idea if:

a) is this the correct solution? Or could I somehow get my web page to behave correctly without the need of an intermediary server?

b) how can I implement this in ASP.NET MVC4? Is there any support for server side timers?

c) even if I can get IIS to retrieve the data every minute, should I then store it in a database to serve it to my web page?

d) the api server I'm talking about is [The Times Newswire API](http://developer.nytimes.com/docs/read/times_newswire_api). If anyone ever used a similar API, did you really created a domain model, a database table, a service and a routine just to retrieve data from it or did you just writed some javascript code in my web page? What then if you have milions of users?

Comment: you need a push service. check out http://pokein.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the API will ban me if I do more than 1 call per minute

Then you need a solution that calls the API for you every minute and stores it on your server. There's tons of ways of doing this, depending on many requirements. You can even go as far as writing a static HTML file which you then show the client.

Comment: so I should write the static HTML every minute, right? - how can I do that?

Comment: Many ways. Your question has two problems. First is _"How do I run a background task on an interval"_ and second is _"How do I cache data"_. Both questions have a lot of answers and are answered many times on SO, do a search. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use SignalR for this purpose, This is a push service which works by using sockets and therefore can be configured to send out one message to 1,000,000 listeners (or more obviously).

I've used this to great effect when creating a little prototype game last year and found it to be very reliable. You can use NuGet to grab the package in vs2010 and vs2012.

see [Asp.net SignalR](http://signalr.net/), see [examples](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs) or simply google SignalR and you'll find a host of examples.

Comment: This SignalR sounds like what I need - I will try it out and checkmark if I'm able to retrieve data intelligently from the API.

Comment: i guarantee, you'll get hooked by it -i know i did :)

Comment: SignalR is not the solution to the problem stated by OP. It's just a way of communicating between browser and server. OP still needs to cache the API response.

Comment: no - the clients would all have the message broadcast to them simultaneously. of course, if your usecase demanded, then you could of course also save the serverside data into the db and issue the last `xx minutes` news to any new subscribers that hadn't been listening to your broadcast. look at the examples and I think you'll see the many different approaches and use cases out there. i used it to create an iphone onscreen simulator that showed in realtime the communication between two real ios devices

Comment: _"issue the last xx minutes news to any new subscribers that hadn't been listening to your broadcast"_ - exactly. If any user visits your site a second after you broadcast the last update, the visitor will see nothing for 59 seconds. So you need a cache.

Comment: wrong - you will alwys give a new user the last broadcast messages straight away (when they request the page) and put them into the broadcast queue. best case scenario, they will actually get the last broadcast messages when they open the page, followed by the update braodcast for all clients a few milliseconds later. there is no worst case scenario, as they will be immediately in the broadcast cycle. but agreed, there needs to be some sort of caching mechanism -db or http cache to mitigate this

Comment: @saturnix - you will of course, as alluded to by CodeCaster, have to look at the persistance options (db or cache) as a first class citizen as this will always be your fallback. this is irrespective of your broadcast strategy

Answer (score 0):

You should call the API from your serverside. Fetch it one time every minute to your database. Then serve it to the users from your database via in example a restful service. ASP.NET MVC 4 can make all of this.

Also yes it do have a timer. You can check out [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) class.

You don't have to struggle with API restricts with this solution.

Comment: If you like [living on the edge](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

A) The best solution is probably to use your web server as an intermediate to the API

B) There are a lot of possibilities to choose from. The easiest would be starting a new thread when the web application starts (i.e in the Global.asax `OnApplicationStarted` event), and have that thread poll the external API and store the result for your clients to fetch. Another options, if you want full control of the lifecycle of this background procces, would be to create a windows service and host for instance a WebAPI in it that you clients can connect to.

Of course, these are just suggestions.

C) Depends on whether you want your clients to be able to access the latest fetch data, even if the background process has failed and the data is old. Otherwise, you can just store it in a static field somewhere. As long as the application isn't terminated the static field persists its value.